# Does SOTag supports minLength?

Tags: jquery

I am using SOTag ([GitHub link](https://github.com/iog3/SOTag)) in one of my application.

Right now on every key up the request goes to server.

What i am curious to know is whether there is a option of minLength available in SOTag similar to jquery autocomplete?

I want the request should go to server only when user has entered atleast 3 characters.

Comment: take a look at line 126 of the script, there you check for length of input

Comment: thanks john for replying. line no 126 checks whether tag is already in the list it does not check for input length. i checked by changing the value but still server request is executed for every key up.

Comment: commented as answer ;-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go, the correct line would be 227

```
        elem.bind('keyup', function () {
            //here you could prevent updating by checking the input length, warning pseudo-code

            if(elem.val().length > 3){
                so_update_results();
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        });
```